# Scaling Socket.IO and broadcast to all belonging clients

Tags: node.js, redis, scalability, socket.io

I'm using

> Express with "connect-redis" session store

And [I tied it with Socket.IO through configuring "authorization"](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/)

So that I don't have to actually use

```
socket.get
```

Or

```
socket.set
```

To store and retrieve a client's belonging variables.

But I'm not sure that If I broadcast a message to specific group of people, connected in different server, get message successfully.

So that it is truly scaled!

But It seems to be not **truly scaled** but only use Redis as storing values individually.

Also [I tried to use](http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html)

> RedisStore

which is given by **Socket.IO**

does not work.

It is saying

```
DEBUG: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Redis.stringify [as pack] (native)
    at Redis.publish (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/stores/redis.js:106:31)
    at Manager.handleClient (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:646:18)
    at Manager.handleHTTPRequest (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:595:8)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:557:12)
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:112:10)
    at HTTPServer.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1507:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1403:22)
```

## How can I scale Socket.IO with broadcasting to all scaled clients available?

**Edit:** I followed [the Express-Session-Socket.IO tutorial](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) and I have found that
      io.authorization actually makes problem but it is **okay** without **io.authorization**.
      How is that?

Comment: Could you clarify to what specific groups of users you want to broadcast? For example, will those be users in the same channel (socket.join()) or users that are connected to the same url (ie /chat/1 or /chat/2)?

Comment: @mtsr all users in same namespaces or in same channel but in different server (scaled)

Comment: The namespace could be done by simply routing those users to the same server. With channels that would be more difficult, because channels are joined after the connection is established.

Comment: @mstr Beside channels, I think the hard point is that let socket.io server broadcasts to all the belonging people who are in different server but in same namespace. How can I do this?

Comment: @InspiredJW It's strange my version of RedisStore is not working for you. Which version of Socket.io are you using? I wrote the example with 0.8.7

Comment: @elranu I'm using the latest - 0.8.7

Comment: @elranu I have found the problem! I added the problem to **Edit**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO has his own authorization. It authorize for each socket. To customize the socket.IO Auth, using my code, write inside the `io.configure` function:

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
       //your auth logic 
});
```

With my example [RedisStore](http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html) you scale to all bradcasting clients available.

Comment: When authorization is successful, I should call **callback(null, true);** But this callback function actually causes the problem :(

Comment: Without the callback function, RedisStore works well. Some people say that it has memory leak problems. Is it true? Also I have found that I have to use **Redis.get() and Redis.set()** Instead of using **Socket.get() and Socket.set()** for storing values. I Hope I can dynamically join and leave rooms. Without disconnecting my connection to leave all rooms at once.

Comment: @InspiredJW When I call the callback(null, true), I do not get an error. About the leaks at the moment I do not have them. In my code you will see that I use client.broadcast.to(Room).json.send, internally Scoket.io Do the set to Redis.
I dont know what you are asking. But I almost sure you can call also  the disconnect. Read the wiki: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io

Comment: Thx man. Room join and leave feature works well with Socket.io. I've looked up RedisStore source file and found that you have implemented with RedisClient subscribe and unsubscribe functions.